# Rails Devise access to User model added columns

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I can't access the columns that I added to the User model I created with Devise.

- Steps I took:

  1. Added Devise gem and created User with rails generate devise User.
  2. Added two columns - first_name and last_name to User with a
     migration and ran it.
  3. Configured permitted parameters so I can
     access those fields (first_name and last_name) while Sign Up and
     Account Update:

before_filter :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?
protected

def configure_permitted_parameters
  devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up, keys: [:first_name, :last_name)
  devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:account_update, keys: [:first_name, :last_name])
end

- Problem:

After I log in I want to display current_user.last_name, but I can’t access it.
I can access default columns - current_user.email, current_user.id.

- Question:

Does anyone know what should I configure to be able to display current_user.last_name?

Comment: Are you getting an error?  It looks to me like your setup is correct, did you verify that the last name and first name got saved to the db?  Can you post the code you have tried so far?

Comment: You don't have to configure anything. What happens when you try to display it, an error or just empty?

Answer (score 0):

I found my problem: I was using `attr_accessor`s on the User model.

By using `attr_accessor` I overwritten ActiveRecord methods with plain ruby versions that don’t persist the value to the database.

I removed it and it works now.